Data type mismatch error in criteria Access SQL
this has been driving me crazy and I’m hoping someone is able to guide what I’m missing. New-ish to SQL (more of a VBA background) and I am trying to get a column to display only positive numbers in the result but I keep running into a Data Mismatch error.
SELECT TEST.[Sample Number], Sample.Title,

IIf(IsNull([Date]),"",DateAdd("m",[Review Cycle],[Date])) AS [Revision Due],

IIf([Revision Due]="","",DateDiff("ww",[Revision Due],Date())) AS [Weeks Overdue]

FROM TEST

WHERE DateDiff("ww",(IIf(IsNull([Date]),"",DateAdd("m",[Review Cycle],[Date]))),Date()) > 0;

I’m sure it’s something glaringly obvious that I’m missing. I know that I’m taking dates and trying to filter them on a numerical value based on weeks something is overdue by.  Thank you.

One problem with your expressions is returning empty string when field is Null. This results in all values return as a string and not a true date or number. Then your sort/filter will follow alpha sort/filter. This is source of error in the WHERE clause because of comparing empty string to 0 for those records that have Null. Return Null or 0, not empty string.
WHERE DateDiff("ww",(IIf(IsNull([Date]),0,DateAdd("m",[Review Cycle],[Date]))),Date()) > 0;

Also advise not to use reserved words as names. Date is a reserved word. Best to avoid spaces and punctuation/special characters in naming convention as well.

Thank you so much, it runs! Didn’t realize the empty string would conflict.  I’ve just recently taken this project over and my next task is to fix the names as reserved words are used everywhere.

I do not allow empty string in tables and don't use it in code comparisons if I can avoid.

When you ask folks to examine your query expressions it is a good idea to provide full context: specifically list all fields (with type details, modifiers) from the TEST table or view.
General troubleshooting tip:
Isolate the offending piece by stripping down your query to bare bones - until only 1 thing is left that that one thing causes the error.
For example try
SELECT Iif(TEST.[Revision Due]="","empty","good") as tst1 FROM TEST;

... and this thing causes error, check type of [Revision Due] to be comparable with the string "".
I'll gladly update this answer once you provide more context!

Apologies, the context is that the query successfully runs if I don’t have any criteria listed (WHERE statement).
Review Cycle is a number field that lists the number of months between review periods (i.e 36). The Date field is the date of last review so this query is to catch items that are overdue and list that number in weeks. I don’t care about items that are current so i am trying to only list positive weeks which are those that are overdue based on the present date.
